# "Please enter SETUP to recover BIOS setting" message on boot

Tags: motherboard, bios, cmos

When I boot the PC it gives the following error:

> Please enter SETUP to recover BIOS setting
>
> Press F1 to run SETUP
>
> Press F2 to load default values and continue

I have tried to set these settings, but it come out every boot time. It can't save these settings.
I use an ASUS P5QL/EPU motherboard.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide more information about the mainboard you are using and what particular bios? Have you checked that the bios battery is still ok? Corrupted settings might indicate that you have an empty battery (depending on the system, probably not valid for newer EFI based system which can store some data in NVRAM)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the battery backing up the BIOS settings is dead. Replace the battery should help.

Comment: What type of battery should I buy for this?

Comment: @KovacsAkos The old battery will have something like "CR2032" stamped on it. If that is exactly what it says, then obtaining a replacement will be easy as it is a widely used part.

Comment: @KovacsAkos this asus motherboard uses the same "CR2032" battery as almost all other asus motherboards do. You can easily buy them for cheap on amazon http://amzn.to/1xfz3Fp (non-affiliate link)

Answer (score 3):

Your motherboard is old so it's likely the internal battery the problem.
This is the battery: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CR2032_battery
You can find it, usually, in place like Auchan or Tesco (cheap) or in a computer shop.
Here you can see where is the battery:
http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5QLVM_EPU/gallery/
in the first image is located just under the yellow ASUS!

Remeber: the operation per se is simple but it require some competence if you are not sure dont do it yourself!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same exact motherboard and this error is familiar to me. Indeed you have a bad battery on that board. It can't keep the BIOS settings saved anymore. You need to replace it with a new one for this message to stop appearing. Or ignore this message altogether if you don't need any non-default settings, it's safe like that. (at least nothing happened to my computer in 6 years)